# How can I convert an InfoPath 2013 form template to a SharePoint 2013 list form template?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, infopath, list-form, list-template

I need to create a SharePoint solution for an IT requirements process. One of the customer's must-haves is to be able to export or save a distinct document as a record copy 'case file' for each IT requirement when it is completed. The document's preferred format is PDF. I've used InfoPath Designer to generate a SharePoint form library. All was fine until I learned we'll be migrating to SharePoint Online E1 plan, which does not include the Forms Service (and therefore no form libraries). Initially we will not have access to PowerApps or Flow (because they have to be cleared by our cybersecurity office first). To adapt my approach to this coming change while not having to start from scratch I hoped there would be a way to convert my existing InfoPath form template to a SharePoint list template. Is this possible? All the use cases I find discussed online and in books assume use of a form library. I want to convert the xsn template currently used with my form library to be a form template for a SharePoint list.

Comment: Also, I have only the front-end web interface, SharePoint Designer 2013 (constrained to 2010 workflows), and (until October 2013) InfoPath Designer 2013. We cannot use any third-party commercial or custom web parts, add-ins, or other custom code.

Comment: yikes, this sounds like a horrible scenario, the only way i know is that you will have to create a list for each different form you had and transform every form to a list item